# Solving and Plotting an integral function

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I am new in the use of Mathematica, so please forgive me..

I want to integrate and plot the following integral function:

$F(x)=\displaystyle\int_x^\infty\dfrac{t\sqrt{t^2-x^2}}{e^t-1}\text{d}t$:

where $x>0$ is the argument of my integral function.

Mathematica doesn't manage to do the calculation, not even if I substitute the x inside the square root with a number, e.g. 1.

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: @MarcoB. Please indicate which answer(s) are relevant.

Comment: Please provide the code you used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem can be solved numerically:

```
F[x_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[(t Sqrt[t^2 - x^2])/(Exp[t] - 1), {t, x, Infinity}]
Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it was silly I guess... Just a brief question: what is the meaning of using "?NumericQ" in the argument of the function?

Comment: @EmanueleCopello - Look at the documentation for [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html). Any function which uses numeric techniques such as `NIntegrate` can only evaluate if its argument(s) is/are numeric, so the argument(s) should be restricted to being numeric.

Comment: Ok thank you.
What if I have to evaluate it in this way:
$F(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n\displaystyle\int_{x_j}^\infty\dfrac{t\sqrt{t^2-x_j^2}}{e^t-1}\text{d}t$
where $x_j$ should be a list of values I have to insert somehow...
What is the best computational way to do it?

Comment: The sum(!)  doesn't depend on x and therefor doesn't define `F[x]`!

Comment: Ok sorry, I have to specify that better.. My function is in fact this one:

$F(T)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n\displaystyle\int_{m_j/T}^\infty\dfrac{t\sqrt{t^2-(m_j/T)^2}}{e^t-1}\text{d}t$

Comment: Ok, what's the reason not to calculate the single summands numerically as proposed in my answer?

Comment: Yeah I want to do that, but I would like to know how to manage the list of $m_j$ variables. I am supposing to sum lots of pieces and I would like not to rewrite the function every time, but just using some kind of list of values to sum on, as much as I would do in a for cycle with arrays and stuff like that...

Comment: I want to sum over something like

`F[x_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[(t Sqrt[t^2-(m[i]/x)^2])/(Exp[t] + 1)/(2*Zeta[3]), {t, m[i]/x, Infinity}]`

where m[i] is an array of values.. Can I define an array of functions like `F[x,i]` and then sum over i? It doesn't seem to work indeed...

Comment: Again the function you are asking for has changed...With the definition I gave in my answer you can solve the sum you called "F[T]": `Total[Table[F[m[i]/T],{i,1,n}]`